# Update DocumentPublishTo date with Kentico API

Tags: kentico

We're trying to update a Document's DocumentPublishTo date with the Kentico API.

The code snippet below updates the property (I can see it change in the UI). However, the document is still published. Also, notice that the DocumentPublishTo only updated after we started updating the DocumentName as well... Any thoughts?

```cs
public void RejectPublishedTranslations(IEnumerable<string> cultures)
{
    var publishStop = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);

    var translatedDocs = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Path("/500").Culture(cultures.ToArray()).CombineWithDefaultCulture(false);
    foreach (var document in translatedDocs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unpublish culture {0} for document {1}", document.DocumentCulture, document.NodeAliasPath);
        document.DocumentName = document.DocumentName; //apparently needs to be called so kentico can actually store the DocumentPublishTo property

        document.DocumentPublishTo = publishStop;
        Console.WriteLine("IsPublished {0}", document.IsPublished);
        document.Update(true);
        document.Publish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the documents under a workflow? Does the workflow have check-in/check-out enabled? Which version of Kentico are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using workflow, you'll need to [advance it through workflow](https://docs.kentico.com/display/API9/Page+workflow+and+versioning#Pageworkflowandversioning-MovingapagetothePublishedstepoftheworkflow) as well.  This should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Seems to me like just implicitly calling _document.Publish();_ listed above would take care of that, right? Unless I'm missing something from the sample listed, such as side effects from just getting the workflow info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do that, if you just want to unpublish the document because it is no longer valid, consider using Archive().

**Now to your original question:**

Publish method moves the document through workflow until it reaches the Published workflow step.

BUT ... this is valid for a document which is not in a published step, it it is, it probably won't do anything except for some rare cases.

You should perform **CheckOut()** - creates a new version for editing, if document is not in published step, it jumps to edit step (starts new workflow cycle)

Edit the properties and call **Update()** - Saves the version properties

Perform **CheckIn()** - Unlocks the document for editing and moving in workflow

Then perform **Publish()** - Moves the document through workflow and "publishes" the last version at the end.

Also check the value of **DocumentPublishFrom**, it shouldn't be in future if you want to apply those changes immediatelly.